# Case in SQL after In statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have the following SQL statement

```
(
    Select top 1 R.[Date] from dbo.[RTable] R where R.x
    IN (SELECT Number FROM dbo.xTable) 
    --(CASE when R.[date]> GETDATE() then 'y'
    --else
    --'n' end) 
    )as FieldName,
```

how to apply the case ? I comment it because it fail on Run , any help ?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: What are you expecting the values `y` and `n` to do? It's not clear. Also, `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY` is almost always indicative of an error waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem using this

```
(Select top 1(CASE when R.[date]>= GETDATE() then 'y' when R.[Date] is null then 'n' else 'n' end) 
from dbo.[table] R  where R.x=a.y) as field,
```

Comment: `WHEN <condition> THEN <value> ELSE <same value>` is redundant. If `<condition>` is true, or if `<condition>` is false, you're always going to produce the same value, so don't bother with testing `<condition>`, just have the `ELSE`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're wanting to do, but it looks a bit like you should have that as part of your select list:

```
SELECT TOP 1 R.[Date], 
    CASE when R.[date]> current_timestamp then 'y' else 'n' end as FieldName 
FROM dbo.[RTable] R 
WHERE R.x  IN (SELECT Number FROM dbo.xTable)
```